# class 'Anonymous class derived from PlaceSelectedListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement the google auto complete widget with some code from the Google website. I'm having one error on this line:

```
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener()
```

the error being:
***class 'Anonymous class derived from PlaceSelectedListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onError(Status)' in 'PlaceSelectionListener'***

and the other error on this one:

```
@Override
public void onError(AsyncTask.Status status
```

whereby the error is: ***Method does not override method from its superclass***

Can I please get insight on how to solve these errors?

```
public class Preferences extends FragmentActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final String TAG = Preferences.class.getSimpleName();


    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());

            String placeDetailsStr = place.getName() + "\n"
                    + place.getId() + "\n"
                    + place.getLatLng().toString() + "\n"
                    + place.getAddress() + "\n"
                    + place.getAttributions();
            text.setText(placeDetailsStr);
        }

       @Override
        public void onError(AsyncTask.Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:
I changed:

```
 @Override
            public void onError(AsyncTask.Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
```

to:

```
@Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
```